# Wifi stops working (on my laptop) after connecting rpi as ethernet gadget

Tags: wifi, ssh, ethernet, pi-zero-w

So I am using a raspberry pi zero W as an ethernet gadget. I got ssh working and the RNDIS/Ethernet Gadget thing working so I can log into the pi using pi@raspberry.local. I even got VNC to work so that I can work remotely.

However, the problem is that when I plug in the rpi into my laptop, it says that I'm connected to the wifi but I have no connection when I search something on my browser. So I can't access youtube while connected nor apt-get anything which kind of ruins the whole remote access capability. Same on the rpi, I am connected to wifi but I can't use chromium for anything.

I'm living in a hotel right now so I can't create a static ip address and ssh into it (already tried but failed with some connection unreachable issue with the router and I can't change the port to something else). Is there any way possible that I can get wifi while still connected to my rpi as ethernet gadget?

Comment: This is a problem of your laptop, not of the PI. I think your laptop uses the PI as a default gateway with higher priority.

Comment: is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of this commands from the RasPi to it: `ip addr` and `ip route`. Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.